# JasperReports jrxml to a java file

Tags: jasper-reports

New to JasperReports in general but I've received a couple of jrxml files. I see that these can be converted to java files but I've been unable to get it working. The samples seem to create a build.xml file and running ant writeapi against the jrxml file but there is no content in the sample

```
<target name="writeApi" description="Generates a .java version of the report by converting the .jrxml file.">
        <ant dir="../" target="writeApi"/>
    </target>
```

Any expertise available ?

Answer (score 0):

> Report template source files having the *.jrxml file extensions are compiled into serialized object files having the *.jasper file extension, just like Java source files having the *.java file extension are transformed into Java bytecode binary files with the *.class file extension.

While doing this jasper report generates .java files that represents the .jrxml and then they create the .jasper files.

I have never used the target="writeApi" but a good guess that it is similar to

```
<taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask"> 
  <classpath refid="classpath"/>
</taskdef>


<target name="compile1"> 
  <mkdir dir="./build/reports"/> 
  <jrc 
   srcdir="./reports"
   destdir="./build/reports"
   tempdir="./build/reports"
   keepjava="true"
   xmlvalidation="true">
  <classpath refid="runClasspath"/>
  <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
  </jrc>
</target>
```

Note: `keepjava="true"`, but without generating the .jasper file, hence it only generates the .java files.

If you like to use the specific `JRAntApiWriteTask` that is

> Ant task for batch-generating the Java source file that uses the JR API to create the report design, from compiled report template files or from source JRXML files.

Note it could be useful if you had the .jasper (compiled files) instead of the jrxml files,

you would use an ant similare to:

```
<taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntApiWriteTask"> 
  <classpath refid="classpath"/>
</taskdef>


<target name="writeApi"> 
  <jrc 
   srcdir="./yourreports"
   destdir="./build/java"
   runApi="true"
   >
  <classpath refid="runClasspath"/>
  </jrc>
</target>
```

Note: I have set `runApi="true"`, so that also jrxml files are generated (they are normally more useful.

For documentation on task see: [JRAntApiWriteTask](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/ant/JRAntApiWriteTask.html)